# Polymer paper-dialog-scrollable, inside of paper dialog modal has scrolling issue scroll appears inside dialog content in the mobile view

Tags: css, polymer, scrollbar, web-component, paper-dialog

My `<paper-dialog-scrollable>` feature, inside of a `<paper-dialog>` open `modal`, has an issue with the scrolling capabilities. The scroll bar offsets into the content of the page, only in the mobile view. When I look through all of the styling, specifically if any margins or padding are changing it, I cannot find any correlation.

For context, it is part of an error window of a paper input box.

This is a snapshot of the HTML inside the Polymer Component.

```html
<paper-input-error id="error">
        <paper-dialog autoFitOnAttach="true" opened=[[modalOpen]] modal="true">
          <div class="close-div">
            <paper-button class="close-button" on-Click="_modalClose" autofocus><iron-icon class="close-icon" icon="icons:cancel"></iron-icon></paper-button>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>{{resultMessage}}</h3>
            <template is="dom-if" if="[[resultArray.1]]">
              <paper-dialog-scrollable id="scrollable-area">
                <div class="dialog" id="suggestList">
                  <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[resultArray]]">
                    <template is="dom-if" if="{{_isHeader(item.type)}}">
                      <div class="typeahead-header"><iron-icon class="typeahead-icon" icon="[[item.icon]]"></iron-icon> [[item.value]]</div>
                    </template>
                    <template is="dom-if" if="{{_isValue(item.type)}}">
                      <div>
                        <paper-item on-mouseenter="_mouseenterItem" class="selectable paper-items" value="[[item]]">
                          <paper-ripple></paper-ripple>
                          <span id="error-item">[[item.value]]</span>
                        </paper-item>
                      </div>
                    </template>
                  </template>
                </div>
              </paper-dialog-scrollable>
            </template>
          </div>
          <div class="buttons">
            <paper-button class="text-close" on-Click="_modalClose" autofocus><strong>Close</strong></paper-button>
          </div>
        </paper-dialog>
      </paper-input-error>
```

Anyone had any issue with this sort of structure, or know of any styling that may be causing the scroll bar to offset?

Comment: Few recommendation/mistakes that i can give you after my first look at the code. `autoFitOnAttach` will never work until you write it as `auto-fit-on-attach`(camel casing gets converted to small cased letter preceded by '-'). No need to write `true` for `booleans` writing a property name makes it true.

Comment: Can you provide complete code for your element(along with js and css, if any). That will make it easy to  replicate the issue